# How to specify metadata for GCE in packer?

Tags: google-compute-engine, packer

I'm trying to create a GCE image from packer template.

Here is the part that I use for that purpose.

```
"builders": [
...
    {
        "type": "googlecompute",
        "account_file": "foo",
        "project_id": "bar",
        "source_image": "centos-6-v20160711",
        "zone": "us-central1-a",
        "instance_name": "packer-building-image-centos6-baz",
        "machine_type": "n1-standard-1",
        "image_name": "centos6-some-box-name",
        "ssh_username": "my_username",
        "metadata": {
            "startup-script-log-dest": "/opt/script.log",
            "startup-script": "/opt/startup.sh",
            "some_other_custom_metadata_key": "some_value"
        },
        "ssh_pty": true
    }
],
...
```

I have also created the required files. Here is that part

```
"provisioners": [
...
  {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "{{user `files_path`}}/startup.sh",
      "destination": "/opt/startup.sh"
  },
...

  {
      "type": "shell",
      "execute_command": "sudo sh '{{.Path}}'",
      "inline": [
          ...
          "chmod ugo+x /opt/startup.sh"
      ]
  }
...
```

Everything works for me without "metadata" field. I can create image/instance with provided parameters. but when I try to create an instance from the image, I can't find the provided metadata and respectively I can't run my startup script, set logging file and other custom metadata.
Here is the source that I use https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html#metadata.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The metadata tag `startup-script` should contain the actuall script not a path. Provisioners run after the startup script has been executed (at least started).

Instead use [`startup_script_file`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html#startup_script_file) in Packer and supply a path to a startup script.